# Python - print all json files under root directory

Tags: python, json, directory

I am trying to print the contents all `json` files contained in sub `dirs`, like so:

```
root/

    folder1/
            client.json
    folder2/
            client.json
```

for that I'm using:

```
    rootdir = 'path'

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for f in files:
            print f
```

which prints:

```
client1.json
client2.json
```

but when I try to perform this operation:

```
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
            for file_ in files:
--------------->with open(file_) as f:
                    print json.load(f)
```

I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client.json'
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Use ```os.path.join(subdir, file_)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to open client.json, but there's no such file in the working-directory of the script, you have to specify the directory it is in:

```
json.load(os.path.join(subdir, file_))
```